# Make browser go to different url on button click?

Tags: javascript

I've got a jquery-ui button. When clicked, I want to move the browser to a url within my domain:

```
<button onclick='foo'>Go</button>

function foo() {
    window.location('/otherpage');
}
```

is that the right way to do it, and address it relatively? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an `<a>` tag?

Comment: In your example you need brackets on the call to foo - ie onclick='foo();'. As it stands the code will execute but won't do anything (the onclick will just return an object containing the foo function ready to be called)

Answer (score 2):

`$('#button-id').click(function() { window.location.pathname = '/otherpage'; });`

What do you mean by relatively? To the current page or to the current host? There are a few options you are able to use.

Comment: +1.  This solution requires jQuery, but it doesn't require a javascript onclick attribute in the html code, which is nice.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming a jQuery solution should be the one considering the question asker is using jquery-ui.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `window.location = '/otherpage';` Other than that I think it's fine.